# Generating function, finding coefficient (decomposing)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I just started learning about generating functions, and there is a problem that I have the solution to, but I'm wondering if there is a better general method to solve problems of that kind.

If I want to find the coefficient of $x^8$ in

$$\left( 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 \right) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k {-2 \choose k} x^k, $$

is there a better method than to decompose it as

$${-2\choose 8}-{-2\choose 7}+{-2\choose 6}-{-2\choose5}+{-2\choose4}$$

$$={9\choose8}+{8\choose7}+{7\choose6}+{6\choose5}+{5\choose4}$$

$=35$?

It is the suggested method in the literature, but it seems to me there should be a better way, since this method would take a lot of time if the coefficient was, for example, the coefficient of $x^{20}$ or larger.

**Edit**

I found a somewhat similar thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70374/finding-a-particular-coefficient-using-generating-functions?rq=1), and tried to apply that method, but that gives me the wrong answer. That method dealt with partitions, so that in my case the term $x^8$ can arise from $x^4 \cdot p(4,2)x^4, x^3 \cdot p(5,2)x^5, x^2 \cdot p(6,2)x^6, x \cdot p(7,2)x^7$ and $1\cdot p(8,2)x^8.$

Counting all such partitions gives me the answer 25, where it should be 35...

Comment: So what can we take for granted? Is the coefficient always on the form $(-1)^k{l \choose k}$?

Comment: Hm. I think so... (Although I have a feeling you are about to tell me that's not right. :) )

Comment: I don't know. I was just wondering what types of sums or series you were curious about :)

Comment: My mistake, I thought you asked for pedagogical reasons. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no essentially different method available. However there are some techniques, which could help to perform such calculations.

> Note, that the calculcation of $x^8$ and of $x^{20}$ is not essentially different, since it is the polynomial
>   \begin{align*}
> 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4
> \end{align*}
>   which determines in both cases $5$ summands, which are to add. So, if this polynomial has more than $5$ summands, this *could* make the calculation somewhat more tedious.
>
> In fact, if we use summation with the *sigma notation* this can also mitigate the complexity of calculations.

It is also convenient  to use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. We can write e.g.
$$[x^8]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k {-2 \choose k} x^k=(-1)^8\binom{-2}{8}$$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^8]&\sum_{j=0}^4x^j\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k {-2 \choose k} x^k\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^4[x^{8-j}]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k {-2 \choose k} x^k\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^4 (-1)^{8-j} {-2 \choose 8-j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^4 {9-j \choose 8-j}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^4 (9-j)=9\sum_{j=0}^41-\sum_{j=0}^4j=9\cdot5-\frac{4\cdot 5}{2}\tag{3}\\
> &=35
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the rule $[x^n]x^k=[x^{n-k}]$ together with the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator
- In (2) we select the coeffient of $x^{j-8}$ of the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k {-2 \choose k} x^k$
- In (3) we use the formula for the finite geometric series $\sum_{j=0}^{n}j=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

*Note:* This kind of calculation may look somewhat more complicated, but it is independent of the coefficient $[x^k]$ and due to the sigma notation and usage of the finite geometric series it is independent of the number of summands of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

$\begin{align*}
(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4) \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-2}{k} z^k
  &= \frac{1 - z^5}{1 - z} \cdot (1 - z)^{-2} \\
  &= (1 - z^5) \cdot (1 - z)^{-3} \\
  &= (1 - z^5) \cdot \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-3}{k} z^k \\
  &= (1 - z^5) \cdot \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 2}{2} z^k
\end{align*}$

so that:

$\begin{align*}
[z^8] (1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4) \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-2}{k} z^k
  &= [z^8] (1 - z^5) \cdot \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 2}{2} z^k \\
  &= \binom{8 + 2}{2} - \binom{3 + 2}{2} \\
  &= 35
\end{align*}$